# Enhance OS X Save dialogs in Cocoa (and/or Carbon)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hook

I would like to enhance the OS X Standard Save dialog with some features (add some controls).

DefaultFolderX actually achieved this
http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/faq.html
.

They note: 
"This means that Default Folder X loads a small piece of program code into each application's memory space (in RAM) so that it can communicate with Navigation Services, the OS X service that provides the Open and Save dialogs."

The question is, is this the easiest way to do this?
If yes, how would someone start on this endeavor (e.g. what kind of Project in Xcode, how to handle the "hook" mechanism if at all necessary, what documentation to read)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want controls at the bottom of the open/save dialog in your app, the NSSavePanel and NSOpenPanel have a function where you can set your own custom view that will sit on the bottom of the dialog.  If you want to modify the NSOpenPanels and NSSavePanels differently, or across the whole system, that will take a lot of work that might just break every time Apple updates their OS.

Comment: Yes across the whole system would be the goal. So you mean this would have to be a well-maintained application in that case. I'd be okay if this is solvable for major releases however. Any idea where to start looking into how to solve this for the whole system?